# Alpine.js Undefined variable: dispatch

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravelcollective, alpine.js

I am using `alpine.js` in my laravel 7.x application. I am also using `LaravelCollective/html` in order to build a very basic form. The idea here is that I am attempting to change the `href` of my anchor tag based on what `select` input is picked. I am getting the following error: `Undefined variable: dispatch`

Here's my HTML/code:

```
<div x-data="{ url: '{{ route('dogs', ['dog'=>$selectedDog]) }}' }" class="px-4 py-5 sm:p-6">       
          <div class="mt-2">
            {{ Form::select('dogs', $dogs, null, 
              ['class' => 'mt-1 sm:leading-5',
              'x-on:change' => "$dispatch('selection-change', { value: $event.target.value })"]) }}
          </div>
          <div class="mt-6">
            <span class="block w-full rounded-md shadow-sm">
              <a 
                href="{{ route('dog', ['dog'=>$selectedDog]) }}" 
                x-bind:href="url"
                x-on:selection-change.window = "alert('test');"
                class="w-full"> 
                  Go to Dog
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
</div>
```

Changing the `select` input should trigger the `x-on:selection-change.window` event bound to the `window` object on the anchor tag. it seems `$dispatch` is having issues, though.

Comment: Is that happening on PHP or JS side? Also, which version of Alpine are you running?

Comment: I'm importing the latest `alpine@v2.x.x` from cdn. The exception seems to be thrown from the server, although I haven't changed any server-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is seeing `$dispatch` and thinking it's a PHP variable, maybe need to escape the `$` or use strings where interpolation is not allowed

Either:

- escape `$`: `'x-on:change' => "\$dispatch('selection-change', { value: \$event.target.value })"`
- use single quote string: `'x-on:change' => '$dispatch("selection-change", { value: $event.target.value })'`

Comment: Ah that was a silly mistake on my part, good catch.

Comment: I've updated the code in the other answer to match, I don't have a running PHP environment so didn't test it out, it's also my bad haha